# How do I limit how often keys can be pressed on a jQuery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, slider

I've made a slider that uses the left and right arrow keys to move the slide but when pressed to quickly it will bug a little and I was wondering if it's possible to limit the amount of presses in say a second. You can see it here: [link removed]

```
$('#slider-nav div').click(function() {
    $('#slider-nav div').removeClass('selected').addClass('');
    $('#slider-nav div:eq('+($.jcarousel.intval($(this).text())-1)+')').addClass('selected');
})

// Allow left and right keys to control slider
$(document.documentElement).keypress(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    var direction = null;

    // handle cursor keys
    if (code == 37) { // left key
        direction = 'prev';
    }
    else if (code == 39) { // right key
        direction = 'next';
    }

    if (direction != null) {
        $('#slider-nav div.selected')[direction]().click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean with “it will bug a little”? What's the problem?

Comment: Basically the slide animation just can't keep up with the key presses.

Comment: You should use the `keydown` event rather than `keypress` for this, for several reasons: one, you get uniform, unambiguous browser support using just the `keyCode` property of the event (in your current solution, typing a percent symbol will fire the left arrow key). Two, auto-repeating keypresses will fire repeating `keydown` events but not `keypress` events in IE.

Comment: Hmm, I changed it to keydown but now firebug keeps displaying this:

"The 'charCode' property of a keydown event should not be used. The value is meaningless."

Comment: Jaybuz: That comes from jQuery, which mistakenly looks at the `charCode` property when dealing with `keydown` events. It's nothing to worry about, except for the jQuery team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a global variable and then when the key is pressed set it to `getTime()` and then on the next call, check if the difference in the set time and the current time is less than 1000.

```
    var checkTime = 0;
function onKeyPress(){
    var currentTime = new Date()
    if((currentTime.getTime() - checkTime) > 1000){
        //do stuff;

        checkTime =currentTime.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! I'll still accept better solutions though, if there are anyway. :)